# Android GCM registration / device id for push notification is getting changed everytime

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I used this code to get gcm registration id. (**Earlier**)

```
// Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

        // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
        // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);



//        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
//                CommonUtilities.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

        // Get GCM registration id
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

        // Check if regid already presents
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            // Registration is not present, register now with GCM           
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID);


        } else {

            AppSharedPreferences.saveDeviceIDPreference(ctx, regId);

            // Device is already registered on GCM
            if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
                // Skips registration.              



//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
                // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
                // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
                final Context context = this;
                mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // Register on our server
                        // On server creates a new user
                        ServerUtilities.register(context, regId);
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        mRegisterTask = null;
                    }

                };
                mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
            }
        }
```

But, shockingly, it seems to change everytime on execution, **`for the same device and same application`**. Please let me know the possible reason of that.

**EDITED**

modified GCM to the newer version

```
gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
new RegisterBackground().execute();
```

Followed [this tutorial](http://techlovejump.com/android-push-notification-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-google-play-service-library/).

But, still same behaviour, i.e, getting new reg id on every install.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using `GCMRegistrar`? It has been deprecated for over 2 years and as of [April 2015](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9ui5Ywfgqeh) has no guarantee of continuing to work.

Comment: Thanks, lemme have a look at it.

Comment: @ianhanniballake can you please refer me a link for the new one?

Comment: The code in edit is not enough(or accurate) information. Update the question with the complete adjusted code. Also, please note in order to get registration token you have to use Instance ID API now.

Comment: GCM implementation has changed substantially since that article was published (i.e November 12, 2013). Please refer to official documentation before you follow any tutorial online. Here's a good reference: https://github.com/google/gcm